# Google Site transfer ownership of Apps-Script to another owner

Tags: permissions, google-apps-script, google-sites, ownership

I have created a Google Site for my organization but I am leaving.
I have another owner set up for the site.
We noticed this morning when he went to edit a script, the following error at the top of the screen:

```
 You no longer have permission to access this document. If this is an error, contact the document owner.
```

The scripts are visible from the manage site dashboard for the new owners login.  The script opens up and is visible but the "Deploy as Web App" is grayed out (even after adding a new version).  If you try to copy the script, it attempts to but then has a red data storage error.

When editing a page on the web site, the new owner tries to Insert an Apps Script Gadget and none of the published web apps appear.

It is not the same issue that is listed here: [Transfer ownership of a file to another user in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796464/transfer-ownership-of-a-file-to-another-user-in-google-apps-script).

I think Google may have listed it as a bug about a year ago ( http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/3rUT5XRUQ2A )

Anyone have any ideas or am I forced to send each of these to the new owner, have them copy and paste them into new files, set new permissions, and re-insert these apps on each of the affected pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Michael,

I just tried to transfer ownership of a Google Site and Google Script and everything worked well.
Let's try with the sample site. Request access to https://sites.google.com/site/testtransferownership/ and I'll make you an owner and then you should be able to remove me from the list.

Comment: For those watching this thread, AVD set me up as an owner on the test site listed (THANKS!) but did not have any Apps Scripts attached (which is what I'm having the problem with).  In addition, I noticed that the "new owner" cannot use the "copy this site" button on the General page of the Manage Dashboard.  Seems something about the permissions for a new owner is not quite the same as the permissions for the original owner.  Will update thread as more information becomes available.

Comment: Added scripts in above experiment.  Problem I described originally seems to be legitimate.

Comment: The basic workaround for this seems to be to have the new owner go into the apps script, make a copy, deploy the copy, then re-attach (Insert | Apps Script Gadget) on whatever page it was in on the site.

Comment: Problem exists for GAS deployed as a web app as well (15/2/13). Michael's workaround fixed the problem. Deploy as web app menu was greyed out.