# Move document from one docs account to another docs account

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to move some documents from one Google account to another Google account using Google apps script with in the same same domain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer ownership of a file to another user in Google Apps Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796464/transfer-ownership-of-a-file-to-another-user-in-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that this tutorial and example code will help you to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/urlfetch-and-oauth/share-docs-between-domain-users

Comment: hey @Waqar Ahmad, you're good at 'heavy lifting' ;-) thanks for this neat piece of code, works nicely !

Answer (score 1):

With Apps Script [File services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file) you can [share a document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#addEditor) to individuals or copy a document [into a shared folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#addToFolder), but it order to change the Owner, you'll have to use the Drive [Permissions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions) through REST/OAuth. You can do that via Apps Script using [UrlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_urlfetch), but that requires a bit more heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a library for that. I found the following on Google+

Drive
Romain Vialard, Dec 2012

This service provides access to new methods for the Drive Service (DocsList). For now on users can get & add commenters on documents + transfer ownership.

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/driveservice

Class File

Member  Type    Description

addCommenter    String  Adds a commenter to the given file.
 getCommenters   String  Returns all the commenters of the given file.
 getEditors  String  Returns all the editors of the given file.
 getLastModifiedByMe     Date    Returns the date this document was last modified by the current user.
 getLastViewed   Date    Returns the date this document was last viewed in a web browser by any user.
 getOwner    String  Returns the owner of the given file.
 getViewers  String  Returns all the viewers of the given file.
 **transferOwnership     String  Transfer ownership to another user within the same domain**