# How do i automate the transfer of ownership of Google Drive docs

Tags: google-apps

I would like to automate the transfer of ownership of Google drive files from identified users to another user daily.

How best could i do this ?

Comment: Ask vague question get vague answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb and making some assumptions about what you want, but give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129662/script-to-change-owner-of-a-document-in-google-docs) a try.