# can I change a google drive item's ownership through a google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am into a google apps domain and I am the the «super administrator».

I know I can do it via the google apps control panel, though I just would rather prefer to do it via a script, for the control panel way creates a new folder and link the file whose ownership is transferred both to the old and the new folder, a thing I do not like very much.

Comment: Soignani this was already asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796464/transfer-ownership-of-a-file-to-another-user-in-google-apps-script).

Comment: @Jacob: Right, I just forgot it... sorry :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Romain Vialard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370762/romain-vialard) (one of the GAS [top contributors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support)) has created a library that handles that case (among others ;-)
You can find [all the informations on this page](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/driveservice).

Comment: So @Sergeinsas you can with the library of @RomainVilard? In that case  I can remove my comment above.

Comment: @Jacob, you don't have to, your comment was pertinent- and indeed the library allows for ownership change.

Comment: Ok, I just now saw the link to the library on the other thread.

Comment: The link on "all the informations on this page" returns "Page not found".