# How can I force all files in a folder to be owned by the folder owner in Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have several people contributing files to various folders in Google Drive. Each folder is for a specific project, and has an owner account named to match that project title. I want every file (and its descendants) in that parent folder to be owned by that project account. Eg the folder is called "Conferences", and is owned by the user "conferences.events@mydomain.com". All files uploaded/created into Conferences should be owned by the "conferences.events" account.

What is the easiest way to automate this (I've looked for scripts online), and can someone provide a working example? Thanks.

Comment: This is really really useful otherwise Google drive can be proofed nightmare.

Comment: If you're using GSuite, this is now supported by using Team Drives.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

The only way "to force" files in folder be owned by the folder owner is that the the other users only have view access to it.

## Explanation

If users are able to add files to a folder there is no way to avoid that they add files that are owned by other then the folder owner user.

## Workarounds

Instead of allowing users to directly contribute to files to folders, implement other way to add the files to that folder. There are several alternatives:

1. Use Google Forms.
   Google recently added a upload file to Google Forms. It's only available to G Suite users. Reference: [Edit form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839737?hl=en), article from Google Docs Editors Help
2. Create a Google Apps Script Web App.
   A Web App could create a copy of the a file selected by the user or even it could change the file owner.

   - Reference: [Transfer ownership of a file to another user in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796464/)  Q&A from Stack Overflow
3. Create an app using Google Drive API

   - Reference: [Transfer Drive files to a new owner](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247799?hl=en), article from the G Suite Administrators Help