# Trigger execution failure in GAS web app by other users

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-drive-api

I made a web app to copy my google drive folders to other users' drive. To solve the execution time exceed error, I'm trying to create a trigger for a function and make the function start after several minutes. This web app will be executed by other users so I set "Execute as" to "User accessing the web app" and "Who has access" to "Anyone with Google account".

It works as expected when I(the creator of this web app) run the web app but fails when executed by other users. I cannot see any log for this failure since there is no information available at "My Executions" of Apps Script dashboard of both the app creator and users.

I tried to log the execution flow into log sheet, but the execution fails at the very beginning since nothing couldn't be logged for the execution.

How can I make other users run the triggered function by their permission?

Below is a sample code for testing the trigger and execution by other users. (I removed all code for cache since it is relevant to this issue)

#### Code.gs

```
const deleteTrigger = (functionName) => {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach((t) => {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
  });
};


function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function myFunction() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('reStart')
    .timeBased()
    .after(3 * 60 * 1000)
    .create();
}

function reStart() {
  deleteTrigger();
}
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
  <button id="myFunction">myFunction, make trigger</button><br>
  <button id="reStart">reStart by manual</button><br>
  <button id="deleteTrigger">Delete Trigger</button>
  
  <script>
  document.getElementById('myFunction').addEventListener('click', function() {
    google.script.run.myFunction();
  });
  document.getElementById('reStart').addEventListener('click', function() {
    google.script.run.reStart();
  });
  document.getElementById('deleteTrigger').addEventListener('click', function() {
    google.script.run.deleteTrigger();
  });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you initiailize their cache somehow because they cant access your user cache

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (the client-side code is missing)

Comment: @Cooper `var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();` isn't enough for the users to access their cache? They are not accessing my user cache but theirs which created by themselves.

Comment: @Ruben I added `index.html`. If the user create trigger for `restart` function using `myFunction` button, `restart` function fails to start. However, starting the `restart` function manually by clicking `reStart` button works quite well, including reading cache.

Comment: What is the error the other users are getting? Also, for testing it, are the other users on the same domain or they have different gmail accounts?

Comment: @Kessy There is no way to check the error message as far as I tried. They are not on the same domain, all of them including the creator are using personal gmail accounts.

Comment: You are access the 'count' and the 'dstId' properties of the users cache but I don't see where you are initializing them.  Perhaps you don't understand that they are different for every user.

Comment: @Cooper Of course, they should be different for every user and that's why I used the User Cache. The cached variables are user-specific and should be maintained when trigger works. Do I need to initialize the cache other than `var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();` and cache.put?

Comment: I'm simply asking the question did you initial the cache property names.  If you didn't do that in the code for your users then those properties don't exist and the code won't work for them

Comment: @Cooper I don't understand what you mean with the initialization of the cache. The users will initialize the cache when they first open the web app as the cache was defined as a global variable as `var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();` Also when the users click the `myFunction` button, new cache value will be put into their user cache named `cached`. Do you mean I need to do another thing to `initialize` the cache? Anyway, the issue is not about cache, but a trigger.

Comment: The cache is an object that has properties if you don't create the properties then you can access them.  In your previous code you only had gets but didn't show any sets so that was the question where are the sets

Comment: @Cooper There was this part if you missed. 

  `cache.put("count", cached ? cached + 1 : 1, 1500);
  var dst = {id: "AAA"};
  cache.put("dstid", dst.id, 1500);`

Comment: Have you tried if the web app works without the cache? Maybe setting a simple log when executed by the other users? Also where does this cache sits on the code?

Comment: Try running the app as another user with dev tools open and inspect the network tab. Under the hood, `google.script.run` issues a request. If the response contains something like "authorization required", it is possible that they are logged into multiple accounts. Alternatively, if these are external users, ask them to open it in incognito mode while being logged into exactly one account. If it works, nothing else you can do. Also, there is a known issue that users running web apps deployed to run as them are not presented with auth screen, so when the script runs, it runs without their auth

Comment: @Kessy I removed code regarding cache since the issue happens regardless it. So, cache was not an issue. Is there a way to make a log for other users' execution? I tried console.log and Logger.log but it didn't return any log for other users' execution.

Comment: @Oleg Valter I tried the incognito mode but same failure happens. Only when the function is executed via timed trigger, the issue happens. I wonder if the web app cannot be executed via trigger as other users.

Comment: @nkink - so, you mean the problem is with the installed trigger run, not with installing the trigger via the web app? The wording that the web app fails confused me as it is a common issue. Is the trigger installed successfully in both cases?

Comment: @Oleg Valter Yes, the trigger is installed successfully but the trigger fails to start. It dies as soon as it starts without executing any code.

Comment: @nkink - can you wrap its body up into a `try...catch` then, add back the code logging errors and see if anything shows up? Also, does the script use standard or default GCP? I'd advise switching to a standard one, so if this is an auth issue, you will see the log in Stackdriver. Probably also a good idea to edit back the `CacheService` code as it might be relevant - if that's an auth issue, then it is likely the trigger dies because of trying to access the unavailable service

Comment: I would also advise you from accessing cache or properties services in the global scope. Move the accesses in respective functions - you do not gain anything performance-wise, but get issues with parsing order (with multiple files), authorization and, besides, you create a global variable, which is an issue in itself. Also - please stick to `let/const` or `var`, they should not be mixed (the former is preferrable unless you are stuck with Rhino - but arrow funcs suggest you aren't)

Comment: also also, in the `myFunction`, the `data` variable leaks to global scope (unless this is a typo)

Comment: @Oleg The web app is running in standard mode not GCP. I wonder if I can see log for other users' execution. When I check the apps script dashboard of the user who set the trigger, I couldn't see any logs.

Comment: @Oleg I think you are seeing older revision of this post. I removed all the code about cache and data.

Comment: @nkink there is no such thing as "standard mode" :) Both run using GCP, but Apps Script creates a default one under the hood, these are called "default" ones. You can switch to a "standard" one and use the Stackdriver logging dashboard to catch auth errors. Installed triggers do not run in web app context - the only important thing is that web app deployment type determines what the effective user is for the trigger.

Comment: @nkink - everyone can see revisions of the posts, you can't remove them entirely, so I took a look at one in the meantime and gave additional feedback. Did you remove everything, does the code look exactly like how it is presented now? Do try wrapping the body in error handling before logging. If nothing comes up, switch GCPs and inspect Stackdriver - authorization issues show up there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending useless time and efforts, I found out the **time-based trigger is not working in V8.**

Check out https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/VTPmr05Gs8k/m/vdH7jWTfBwAJ for details.

Comment: Good find - although none of my projects are affected by anything similar, so it is too much to say the triggers do not work in V8. Probably a bug on Google's side then.

Comment: To be specific, it is reported that the time-based trigger executed as other users and accessible for all google account users is not working as expected.

Comment: huh, half a decade in, but we still get really bad issues related to authorization :(

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is only happening with V8 runtime on, you can create an issue on Google's Issue Tracker, on the [apps script component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640)

Comment: Already done by other users. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612 You can see the link on the google community post.