# How do I remove myself as an owner of a document using app scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, document

I have tried this but the document still stays in my google drive.

```
doc = DocumentApp.create('document')
     doc.removeEditor('myself')
```

I know i cant remove myself but is there any way to avoid it.

```
doc = DocumentApp.create('document')
     doc.removeEditor('myself')
```

what will work. In short I want to add someone else to the document and remove myself.

Comment: In your situation, when the permission of you who is the owner of Google Document is removed from Google Document, who is the new owner of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer ownership of a file to another user in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796464/transfer-ownership-of-a-file-to-another-user-in-google-apps-script)