# App script for change ownership of the a particular sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for an Apps Script that can change the ownership of a particular Sheet I have. Did some but it transfers all the files in my drive to the other person. Can you help me on how to set so that only the sheet would transfer owners.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796464/transfer-ownership-of-a-file-to-another-user-in-google-apps-script) helpful for you?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful if you provided some piece of code that has caused the problem so that we can better help you in resolving your issue! :)

Comment: hi how to add the code here